# Call a function every 30 sec

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, refresh

I have a page function which needs to be called every 30 sec.
How can i do that?

Here is the code i need to call:

```
protected void GetMachines_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    ArrayList machinesList = new ArrayList();

    GetValFromMachines(machinesList);
}
```

Please help.. Thanks

Comment: To clarify, how do you need this to be called?  On the server?  (In which case a separate thread is best so it's not blocking anything with the web application.)  Or from the client?  (In which case the client has the option of stopping this call from happening.)

Comment: If you use the <asp:Timer> as suggested below (which will work btw), it will likely cause a full postback unless wrapped in its own updatePanel, is this desired?

Comment: david.. it should be a client.. so i was thinking of putting a checkbox which if checked will stop the auto refresh..

Comment: kd7.. i do not want a complete postback i just want that function GetMachines_Click to be called.. is that possible?? thanks guys

Comment: it would be great if anyone knows a sample case code for an issue like this? thanks

Comment: The GetMachines_Click method needs to be exposed on the server as a callable endpoint, e.g., a REST endpoint or a web service.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<asp:Timer>` control for this.

http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+timer

It requires the use of the `<asp:ScriptManager>`

**edit**

This will cause a full post back of the page, so you will want to put an `<asp:UpdatePanel` on the page to update only the content you wish.

However, I stopped using the `<asp:Timer>` and `<asp:UpdatePanel>` in favour of doing this sort of update using WCF Ajax Services. You can add a reference to the WCF service in your ScriptManager, which then allows you to call the methods through Javascript. I feel it just gives you greater control over how much data is being passed through AJAX and also stops the full page post back.

Comment: hey thanks.. this WCF looks interesting.. please can you point me to a sample where you read it from..?

Comment: This could be a starting point http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx